# Spring Boot @ConditionalOnProperty doesn't load bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, configuration, conditional-statements

I'm trying to implement a service, which will use two different repositories based on `env` variable.

Based on this article: https://reflectoring.io/dont-use-spring-profile-annotation/

I want to use configuration with `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation to load appropriate implementation on startup.

I did everything exactly like in the article, but spring throws an exception saying that the bean is not defined:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of method myService in com.adam.MyServiceConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.adam.MyRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.adam.MyRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the configuration of service:

```
@Configuration
class MyServiceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun mySerivce(myRepository: MyRepository) = MyService(myRepository)
}
```

And here is the configuration of repository beans:

```
@Configuration
class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
        prefix = "datasource",
        name = ["mock"],
        havingValue = "false",
        matchIfMissing = true
    )
    fun myRepository(httpClient: HttpClient): MyRepository =
        HttpRepository(httpClient)

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
        prefix = "datasource",
        name = ["mock"],
        havingValue = "true"
    )
    fun myRepository(): MyRepository = InMemoryRepository()
}
```

Can anybody see what am I doing wrong? I'm struggling with it for hours.

I tried using @DependsOn but then the error was that there is no bean defined of that name.

I also enabled logging and if I'm reading this right the bean should be resolved properly:

```
   My#repository:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (datasource.mock=false) found different value in property 'mock' (OnPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (datasource.mock=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `@Bean` methods named `myRepository` on one `@Configuration` class. This means that there are two different methods both defining a bean named `myRepository`. This confuses Spring Framework's condition evaluation as described in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22609). The confusion means that the conditions on both `myRepository()` methods are evaluated when defining a single `myRepository` bean. Your two conditions are mutually exclusive so no bean is defined.

You can fix the problem by ensuring that your two `@Bean` methods have distinct names. For example you could name them `httpRepository` and `inMemoryRepository`.